# Python postgresql variable declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I would like to ask how can I declare the variable "mobile" on the sql query?
I can print the mobile using .format() but it ain't working on the query cur.execute(). How should I declare the "mobile" variable for the query to update my database?
Also for your information I have a text file which named currentNum.txt and the only value inside is 639662146331(please take note that this should a string)
Thank you in advance!

```
import psycopg2
import os

try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='database' user='postgres' password='password'")
        print("Connected to database.")
except:
        print("Unable to connect to database.")

cur = conn.cursor()

try:
        list=open("currentNum.txt", "r")
        mobile=list.readline()
# It doesn't update the database 
        cur.execute("UPDATE notif_counter SET status='Notify' WHERE mobile='{0}'".format(mobile))
        conn.commit();
# This is working
        print("Table notif_counter where mobile {0} successfully updated.".format(mobile))
        list.close()
except:
        print("Failed to update the table for notif_counter")
finally:
        if(conn):
                cur.close()
                conn.close()
                print("PostgreSQL connection is closed.")
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting any errors ? Are you sure you have that record in the database ?

Comment: I am not getting any errors but it doesn't update the database in this code It doesn't update the database  ```cur.execute("UPDATE notif_counter SET status='Notify' WHERE mobile='{0}'".format(mobile))

Comment: you are going to get sql injected using this code ... you should really use the bound substitution (although that isnt actually the problem you are facing) you should change to `cur.execute("UPDATE notif_counter SET status='Notify' WHERE mobile=%s",(mobile,)) `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
list = open("input.txt",'r')
mobile = list.readline().strip()
cur.execute("UPDATE notif_counter SET status='Notify' WHERE mobile='{}'".format(mobile))
```

it looks like you have forgot to remove trailing whitespace, use .strip()

Comment: Passing variables to SQL queries using string formatting is error prone and open to SQL injection. The proper way is to use the driver's placeholders and to pass the variables separately to `execute()`.